# Call parent's counterpart inside an overridden method

Tags: javascript, oop, overriding, super

Im designing my own OOP js pattern, but i have a problem when i want to override a method.

```
C1 = function () {};
C1.prototype.method = function ()
{
    // Do stuff
};

C2 = function () {};
C2.prototype = new C1();
C2.prototype.constructor = C2;
C2.prototype.parentClass = C1;
C2.prototype.method = function ()
{
    // Not valid here! 'this.parentClass' references C2 instead of C1
    // when 'this' is a C3 instance.
    this.parentClass.prototype.method.call (this);
    // Do stuff
};

C3 = function () {};
C3.prototype = new C2();
C3.prototype.constructor = C3;
C3.prototype.parentClass = C2;
C3.prototype.method = function ()
{
    this.parentClass.prototype.method.call (this);
    // Do stuff
};

var c3 = new C3 ();
c3.method ();
```

Some people suggests this:

```
[parentClassName].prototype.method.call (this);
```

But, at this way, it is necessary to write (and know) the name of the parent class. I want to do it in a more elegant way.

Is there another way to reference the parent overridden method without writing the parent class name?

Comment: Your problem stems directly from how you are calling the method. If you want a specific *this*, then call the function to set it to that value. Why not within *C3.prototype.method*: `this.parentClass.prototype.method(this)`.

Comment: If you read my post, i said that i want to avoid the use of _[parentClassName].prototype.method.call (this);_ because I'm looking for a more elegant way

Comment: I understood "parent class name" to be the name of the "parentClass", which is "C2".

Comment: I need a _relative_ reference to the overrided metod, that is, without writing **any** class name (Current or parent classes)